Discord.JS Show Modal Error (Announcement Creation Bot)
I am making a command for my bot that when you the /createannouncement it shows a modal that you can put in the information for. it keeps coming up with an error and also in discord saying "The Application Did Not Respond"
this code worked before when i only had it replying to the message and using emphemeral idk why modals hate me but they do,
I followed the discordjs.guide websites guide on it but it just errors and idk why
This Is the code that i have:
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ModalBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('createannouncement')
        .setDescription('Creates An Announcement')
        .addChannelOption(option =>
                        option
                            .setName('announcement-channel')
                            .setDescription('The Channel to Send the Announcement to')),
    
    async execute(interaction) {
        const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('announcement-channel');
        
        const announcementModal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('announcementCreator')
            .setTitle('Announcement Creator');
        
        const announcementTitleInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('announcementTitleInput')
            .setLabel('Announcement Title')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);
        
        const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(announcementTitleInput);
        
        announcementModal.addComponents(firstActionRow);
        
        await interaction.showModal(announcementModal);
        //await channel.send({content: 'your announcement will look like this:', embeds: [announcementEmbed]});
    },
};

And The Error:
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:727:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:831:23)
    at async _REST.request (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1272:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.showModal (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:257:5)
    at async Object.execute (/home/container/src/commands/tools/createannouncement.js:28:9)
    at async Object.execute (/home/container/src/events/client/interactionCreate.js:12:9) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 9, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1300260874266742834/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTMwMDI2MDg3NDI2Njc0MjgzNDpxeDBNTlhpd1FXam95UzhYUHp5b0tXQnRRUmNxRnVwenFMb1BXNXMwOEw2M1VBcElhMTJpbzdSSWQ4eFNERHd1T211OHA0VHFjaFR1MEkyeWoxY01kdEZmakxtS3hVakN2SEFXWjZ3RTVCQXlDRDU2Q3lCcFZKZktqYmVxVUQxMQ/callback'
}
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:727:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:831:23)
    at async _REST.request (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1272:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:115:5)
    at async Object.execute (/home/container/src/events/client/interactionCreate.js:15:9)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Something went wrong...',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        enforce_nonce: false,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: 64,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined,
        applied_tags: undefined,
        poll: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1300260874266742834/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTMwMDI2MDg3NDI2Njc0MjgzNDpxeDBNTlhpd1FXam95UzhYUHp5b0tXQnRRUmNxRnVwenFMb1BXNXMwOEw2M1VBcElhMTJpbzdSSWQ4eFNERHd1T211OHA0VHFjaFR1MEkyeWoxY01kdEZmakxtS3hVakN2SEFXWjZ3RTVCQXlDRDU2Q3lCcFZKZktqYmVxVUQxMQ/callback'
}
Node.js v19.9.0


Can you insert the code of your command handler please?

Based on the code provided, the command handler doesn't defer or reply in a timely manner, and the unknown interaction error is a common error to receive if you continue executing code and don't respond within the 3 seconds window it expects.  I would add a defer/reply code set to your execution handler.  See:
https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.16.3/CommandInteraction:Class
you can also see examples of how to reply and/or defer here:
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#executing-commands
In general, I would defer at the first line of the handler, do your handling, and then reply at the end.
